# Translate unreadable Russian text

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, translation

I'm trying to read documentation which was written in I believe is Russian, but I'm not sure if what I'm seeing is even encoded correctly.  The text looks something like this:

```
Ãåíåðèðóåò ìàòðèöó ñëó÷àéíûõ ÷èñåë â äèàïàçîíå îò -1 äî 1
```

(appears as several special A's and o's)

when opened in Firefox.  In other programs it looks like this:

```
���������� ������� ��������� ����� � ��������� �� -1 �� 1
```

(appears as several question marks)

Is there any hope to translate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decode as CP1251.

```
>>> print u'Ãåíåðèðóåò ìàòðèöó ñëó÷àéíûõ ÷èñåë â äèàïàçîí'.encode('latin-1').decode('cp1251')
Генерирует матрицу случайных чисел в диапазон
```

Comment: "Generates a matrix of random numbers in the range"

Comment: @Johnathan: Correct. Its REPL is great for one-offs like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine which of multiple possible [Cyrillic](http://czyborra.com/charsets/cyrillic.html) codesets was used - the linked site lists more than a dozen possibilities, of which ISO 8859-5 and CP-1251 are perhaps the most likely.

You may be able to get one of the translation web sites ([Babelfish](http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt) or [Google](http://translate.google.com/), and no doubt others) to help.  However, you may have to translate from the original codeset to UTF-8 to get it to work -- simply copying the bytes above did not work.

---

When copying the original text to a Mac, it was encoded as UTF-8:

```
0x0000: C3 83 C3 A5 C3 AD C3 A5 C3 B0 C3 A8 C3 B0 C3 B3   ................
0x0010: C3 A5 C3 B2 20 C3 AC C3 A0 C3 B2 C3 B0 C3 A8 C3   .... ...........
0x0020: B6 C3 B3 20 C3 B1 C3 AB C3 B3 C3 B7 C3 A0 C3 A9   ... ............
0x0030: C3 AD C3 BB C3 B5 20 C3 B7 C3 A8 C3 B1 C3 A5 C3   ...... .........
0x0040: AB 20 C3 A2 20 C3 A4 C3 A8 C3 A0 C3 AF C3 A0 C3   . .. ...........
0x0050: A7 C3 AE C3 AD C3 A5 20 C3 AE C3 B2 20 2D 31 20   ....... .... -1 
0x0060: C3 A4 C3 AE 20 31 0A                              .... 1.
0x0067:
```

So, to translate this with Perl, I used the [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module first to convert the UTF-8 string back to Latin-1, and then I told Perl to treat the Latin-1 as if it was CP-1251 and convert that back to UTF-8:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Encode qw( from_to );
my $source = 'Ãåíåðèðóåò ìàòðèöó ñëó÷àéíûõ ÷èñåë â äèàïàçîíå îò -1 äî 1';
# from_to changes things 'in situ'
my $nbytes = from_to($source, "utf-8", "latin-1");
# print "$nbytes: $source\n";
   $nbytes = from_to($source, "cp-1251", "utf-8");
print "$nbytes: $source\n";
```

The output is:

- 102: Генерирует матрицу случайных чисел в диапазоне от -1 до 1

Which Babelfish translates as:

- 102: It generates the matrix of random numbers in the range from -1 to 1

and Google translates as:

- 102: Generate a matrix of random numbers ranging from -1 to 1

The initial UTF-8 to Latin-1 translation was required because of the setup on my Mac (my terminal uses UTF-8 by default, etc): YMMV.